# Django Test: type object has no attribute 'objects'

Tags: django, django-models, django-testing, django-tests

In my web application, I have locations and respective opening hours. The OpeningHours model looks as follows:

```py
class OpeningHours(models.Model):
    location = models.ForeignKey(
        Location, related_name='hours', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    weekday = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=WEEKDAYS, unique=True)
    from_hour = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=HOUR_OF_DAY_12)
    to_hour = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=HOUR_OF_DAY_12)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('weekday', 'from_hour')
        unique_together = ('weekday', 'from_hour', 'to_hour')

    def get_weekday_display(self):
        return WEEKDAYS[self.weekday][1]

    def get_hours_display(self):
        return '{} - {}'.format(HOUR_OF_DAY_12[self.from_hour][1], HOUR_OF_DAY_12[self.to_hour][1])

    def get_start_hour_display(self):
        return HOUR_OF_DAY_12[self.from_hour][1]

    def get_end_hour_display(self):
        return HOUR_OF_DAY_12[self.to_hour][1]

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}: {} - {}'.format(self.get_weekday_display(),
                                    HOUR_OF_DAY_12[self.from_hour][1], HOUR_OF_DAY_12[self.to_hour][1])
```

I'm trying to test a model similar to how I have successfully tested other models in my application:

```py
class OpeningHours(TestCase):

    def create_opening_hours(self, weekday=1, from_hour=12, to_hour=15):
        self.location = create_location(self)
        return OpeningHours.objects.create(location=self.location, weekday=weekday, from_hour=from_hour, to_hour=to_hour)

    def test_opening_hours(self):
        oh = self.create_opening_hours()
        self.assertTrue(isinstance(oh, OpeningHours))
        self.assertTrue(0 <= oh.from_hour <= 23)
        self.assertTrue(0 <= oh.to_hour <= 23)
        self.assertTrue(1 <= oh.weekday <= 7)
```

, but when running the test I get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<app_path>/tests.py", line 137, in test_opening_hours
    oh = self.create_opening_hours()
  File "<app_path>/tests.py", line 134, in create_opening_hours
    return OpeningHours.objects.create(location=self.location, weekday=weekday, from_hour=from_hour, to_hour=to_hour)
AttributeError: type object 'OpeningHours' has no attribute 'objects'
```

I assume this could have to do with the `ordering` or `unique_together` metadata, but not sure how to solve this... any pointers in the right direction very much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have given `OpeningHours` name to your test class as well as to the model class. So change the name of the test class to anything other than `OpeningHours` will solve the mentioned issue.